# Звідки слово клІйонка?

Tags: етимологія, іменники

Знаю, що правильно використовувати слово ***клЕйонка***, про це пише і [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=42098&page=1330). однак на багатьох сайтах пишуть саме **клІйонка**. Наприклад,  [тут](https://www.dzo.com.ua/tenders/126430), [тут](https://www.olx.ua/uk/obyavlenie/nova-medichna-nepromokayucha-klyonka-IDw4dkE.html), [тут](https://list.in.ua/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) та ін.

Спершу подумала, що, можливо, через вплив російської, однак - ні, там пишуть через Е: *клеенка*.

Тому цікавить, звідки ж взялося у нас слово клІйонка?

Comment: Ось російська транскрипція цього слова: кл'иеjо́нкʌ. Там йде пониження ненаголошеного голосного звуку "є" до "і", тож ви все правильно подумали, що клІйонка - від російського слова.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) знаходимо:

> **Клейонка**, клейончастий; − запозичення з російської мови; р. клеёнка (з 1771 р.) «клейонка» є похідним від клеить «клеїти» ( при сучасному дедалі поширенішому наголосі кле´ить); п. klejonka «бутівка; клеєна фанера; (мн. klejonki) спортивні лижі; штучна шкіра; (перен.) погана компіляція» є, мабуть, незалежним утворенням. Шанский ЭСРЯ ІІ 8, 149.− Див. ще **клей**.